# MediaStyle Notification to Show Button in Compact View

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm using the MediaStyle for my push notification so that I can show currently playing song meta data as well as include a pause button. The issue I'm seeing is that my notification is not automatically expanding to show the pause button, even though I've included the setShowActionsInCompactView(). If I pull down on my notification while on the lock screen, it expands and then shows the pause button. But I would like it to show the button without expanding.

Screenshot of how notification is displayed:
http://cl.ly/image/3E2D0m403v1b

Screenshot of how notification is displayed after pulling down on it to expand:
http://cl.ly/image/1N1i0G121i2Y

Below is the code snippet I'm using to generate the notification:

```
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_PLAYER_STOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setTicker(tickerString)
                .setContentText(contentString)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setLargeIcon(icon)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_media_pause, "", pendingIntent)
                .setContentIntent(pi)
                .setStyle(new android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                        .setShowActionsInCompactView(0)
                        .setMediaSession(mSession.getSessionToken()))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setWhen(0)
                .setOngoing(true);
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.build());
```

Comment: Can you include s screenshot of what you are seeing? And to be clear, you're testing this on an API 21+ device?

Comment: Just updated question with screenshots. Also, I'm testing on Galaxy S6 running Android 5.1.1. But behavior is same on all emulators I've tried.

Comment: Maybe I'm better off just using a custom view with RemoteViews for the notification?

Comment: Could you add screenshots from an emulator? Samsung's notifications don't look anything like what stock Android looks like so it would be nice to have something familiar to compare it to (also note that attaching your `MediaSession` via `MediaStyle` is a requirement for Android Wear controls).

Comment: Updated with screenshots from Nexus 9 API 21 emulator.

Comment: I think the .setStyle() call is not being respected, because if I comment it out, I get the same exact behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use `NotificationCompat.MediaStyle`, you must use the `android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder` - the default v4 Builder does not handle the v7 MediaStyle

Comment: You're awesome. Thank you, that worked! Wow what a pain and waste of time. I wish I posted on here sooner.

Comment: This wasted a lot of time.

Comment: Hello. How can I get the android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat? The Android Studio doesn't locate it?